# Output string with variables replaced with JSON values

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to build a 'generator' that takes an initial text string that is pulled from a base JSON file and contains curly braced content; e.g., {lib:extFile}. That curly braced content is to be replaced by a value that is obtained from a different JSON file. The 'lib' portion of that content indicates the name of the other JSON file. The secondary JSON file value might in turn contain a reference to yet another JSON file.

So simply put, I need to somehow make an AJAX call to retrieve the other JSON files and pull a value from them. The original input string should eventually have all curly braced content replaced by values, some from these other files. So I need some sort of looping or recursion to:

Pull the curly braced value and use that to get a separate JSON file value. Keep going through the values to replace all curly braced content and end up with a final result string to be returned.

I hope that makes sense. I have a lot of this working, although nowhere public at the moment. I just ran into a corner trying to get the other JSON value(s) back into the original string, somehow working around the asynchronous nature of AJAX calls.

Comment: sounds like mustache.js

Comment: *somehow working around the asynchronous nature of AJAX calls*. All I can say is, embrace the chaos :). Don't try and work around asynchronicity; use it. In this case, without seeing code the question is too broad; there are a few dozen ways of doing this. My preference would be to chain promises together, but you could also use a recursive callback structure.

Comment: Poorly worded, I didn't mean work around it, I meant work with it. I can provide the files if you're interested, although I'm guessing that's not best practice and JSFiddle is probably preferred.